# Set window position for launching .exe external application from Java awt window

Tags: java, awt

I want to launch an external application which has an .exe extension from Java code and I want that application to be launched at specific position on user desktop.

How can I detect user window positions and set this exe application to open at a specific position?

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public static void open(String targetFilePath) throws IOException
{
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

    desktop.open(new File(targetFilePath));
}
//targetFilePath = xyz.exe
```

Using above code, xyz.exe gets launched but I want to set its position on left top corner on user window. Currently its appearing at center by default.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible in java by design. Java is supposed to be running in a system agnostic sandbox. Manipulating other processes is something java was explicitly not meant to do.

However you might be able to use platform dependent code through the use of Java Native Interface (JNI).